# Cannot reinstall Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 or 4.51

Tags: .net

I am using Windows 8 and I uninstalled Microsoft Frameworks 4.5 and 4.51 because a blog suggested reinstalling these if I had issues debugging in Visual Studio.  I uninstalled them in the control panel in the programs and features section.  I downloaded the web install frameworks for both from Microsoft's site, but when I run them, I get a message that says "The .net framework 4.5 and this update are already installed on your computer".

I tried a .net cleanup utility, but it says "ERROR Cannot remove product '.NET Framework 4.5' because it is not allowed on the current OS"

I uninstalled the following from the control panel:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.51 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.51 Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.51 SDK

I am not sure how to re-install the .net frameworks or if there is another place I need to go to remove .net framework 4.5 completely before reinstalling it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The things you uninstalled seem to only be from the SDK, not the framework itself. I suspect the framework cannot (easily) be removed.

Comment: .NET 4.5 cannot be uninstalled from Windows 8. In order to reinstall, you need to refresh Windows 8 PC. Could you share blog post that recommends reinstalling?

Comment: I am wandering what is the difference between contents in Multi-Targeting Pack and Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU/english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that Visual Studio 2013 comes pre-installed with .net frameworks 4.5 and 4.51.  The company I worked for already had this installed.  I was going to reinstall it, but I did a repair first by selecting VS 2013 under programs and features and selecting repair.  4.5 and 4.51 are now installed again.

The debugging issues I had (application not stopping at my breakpoint correctly) had something to do with JustMock profiler being enabled.  I have disabled this for now.